# Refactor a method which refer local class and .net class in if else conditions

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring

I am currently trying to re factor a method which preforms certain operations based on type of exception , certainly leading to a lot of if else conditions, in this method the code base looks like this

```
if (exception is DataException)
{
    jobInformation.StatusDescription.DescriptionResourceReference =
        new TextResourceReference(
            typeof(StorageDevices.UserMessageTexts),
            UserMessageDispatcher.DataError);
    jobInformation.StatusDescription.SetParameters(
        new object[] { exception.Message });

}
else if (exception is InsufficientMemoryException)
{
    jobInformation.StatusDescription.DescriptionResourceReference =
        new TextResourceReference(
            typeof(StorageDevices.UserMessageTexts),
            UserMessageDispatcher.InSufficientSpaceInMediaError
            );

}
else if (exception is FileNotFoundException)
{
    if (exception.Message.Contains("DicomViewer"))
    {
        jobInformation.StatusDescription.DescriptionResourceReference =
            new TextResourceReference(
                typeof(StorageDevices.UserMessageTexts),
                UserMessageDispatcher.NoDicomViewer
                );
    }
    else
    {
        jobInformation.StatusDescription.DescriptionResourceReference =
            new TextResourceReference(
                typeof(StorageDevices.UserMessageTexts),
                UserMessageDispatcher.NoMediaOrSourceFileMissing
                );
    }
}
else  (exception is ImapiException)
{
    jobInformation.StatusDescription.DescriptionResourceReference =
        new TextResourceReference(
            typeof(StorageDevices.UserMessageTexts),
            UserMessageDispatcher.MediaBurnError
            );
}
```

As evident, in above code base it can be seen that few exception are custom where as others are .net exception.

Now i would like to re factor this method in such a way so that i can just call

```
exception.SetJobInformation(jobInformation)
```

and move the corresponding logic of exceptions in to exception classes, but avalibility of .net exception classes is posing a challenge to me , any suggestion or solution for this scenario?

Comment: In your code example it looks like you do (nearly) the same for all exception types. Correct?

Comment: No, this is a subset of the if else conditions ,different logic are written for different type of exceptions like different error message allocation in jobinfo

Comment: Invert it? e.g. public ErrorTextResourceReference(FileNotFoundException ex)